# I reset my Chrome browser, now I lost all logins, how do I get them again?

Tags: google-chrome

Facebook, youtube, reddit, quora, etc... all are signed out.

I have another PC which hasn't synced using Internet (still not connected), can I use that to get logins again?

I can manage with some websites, but I'm afraid I would need logins for websites which I have forgot the password of.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/655294/how-can-i-export-chrome-passwords/675167#675167 has some solutions for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can export your passwords using Google Chrome's experimental "Password export" on your other computer.

1. Open Chrome and type `chrome://flags` into the address bar and hit **Enter**.
2. Search for the **Password export** option and use the drop down menu to set it to **Enabled**.
3. Restart Chrome by clicking the **Relaunch now** button.
4. Open **Settings** from Chrome's menu and click the **Settings** menu button in the top left.
5. Click the **Advanced** button to reveal the advanced features
6. Click **Passwords and forms**, then click **Manage passwords**.
7. Click the **More actions** menu (the three dots at the top of the list of saved passwords) and select **Export**.
8. Click **Export Passwords** and you can save your passwords in a CSV file ready to import into the application of your choice.

Note, I couldn't verify steps 6 and 7 myself because I don't store passwords in Chrome.

[source](https://betanews.com/2018/03/09/export-chrome-passwords/)

Comment: Thank you, I did that, but before I enable Internet on the other device, please tell me if this really solves the sign-out problem. I have some passwords on this device where the problem is. The problem is all websites are signed-out, and no specific autofill to use to sign-in. Will simple importing passwords work? (Again, I think both devices have the same passwords, but there still is this problem)

Comment: The CSV file should be human readable, so you at least have a backup of the passwords. Can you try moving the file by USB flash drive without Internet access and import?